# Install mocha on VirtualBox with Ubuntu image

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mocha.js

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox in Windows 7 with an image of Ubuntu 13.04 x86.
I've already downloaded a github project, I've run:

```
sudo npm install -g mocha
sudo npm install mocha
npm install
```

nodejs is installed (nodejs --version retrieves v0.10.25)

If I run:

```
which mocha
```

I get: /usr/bin/mocha

Then, I run:

```
mocha test/test1.js
```

I just get the command prompt, nothing happens, I don't see the tests running.

I went to the mocha folder inside node_modules/mocha and I see two files: mocha and _mocha, I run both and nothing happens

When I say "I just get the command prompt", this is what I can see:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/guillermo/myproject$ mocha --reporters
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/guillermo/myproject$
```

Any advise?
Thanks!!! Guillermo.

Comment: Have you tried running just "mocha" inside the test/ directory?

Comment: You may need to specify a reporter for it to report something. Use `mocha --reporters` to display avaliable reporters. Then do `mocha -R <reporter_name>`

Comment: @Xinzz/@RBK I just get the command prompt, nothing happens in both cases. I went to the mocha folder inside node_modules/mocha and I see two files: mocha and _mocha, I run both and nothing happens...I just get the command prompt

Comment: What do you mean by "just get the command prompt"?

Comment: @Xinzz 

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/guillermo/myproject$ mocha --reporters
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/guillermo/myproject$

Comment: @Xinzz I've added it formatted to the question

Comment: I would check what's in `/usr/local/mocha` since that seems to be what you're running most.  Perhaps `ls -al /usr/local/mocha` then inspect what's actually in that file.  Have you had any problems with other node bin scripts?  Maybe `node` isn't in your path?

Comment: Try doing `which mocha` and maybe `./node_modules/.bin/mocha` if it's running from a different location than you would expect. It's correctly installed and it's running without errors, it just looks like it can't find any tests to run.

Comment: weird...ls -al /usr/local/mocha retrieves "no such file or directory". When I run which mocha it retrieves "/usr/bin/mocha", but I try to go there I can't find the directory. Seems like mocha is not being installed correctly. Any known issues about mocha with ubuntu and VirtualBox?

Comment: I've installed the : sudo apt-get install nodejs then backed up node wrong binary (ax25-node) sudo mv /usr/sbin/node /usr/sbin/nodeBKP
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node taking into account that "which node"
gave me /usr/sbin/node and "which nodejs"
/usr/bin/nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed the wrong Ubuntu package for node.js. If you did `sudo apt-get install node`, then the package "ax25-node" is installed instead of node.js.

See [this](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) page on how to install node.js on Ubuntu using nvm.

If you want to use ubuntu's package repository for node.js, then do `sudo apt-get install nodejs`, and the resulting binary is called `nodejs` instead of `node`.